# Why does current decrease when voltage is increased? (transformers)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage

Why is the current in the secondary coil less than in the primary when the voltage is greater in that coil as compared to primary coil? (for transformers)

Well I know that energy should be conserved but listen this is not the cause! There would be some motion, forces or fields included in reason that finally results in high voltage and low current.

And i also think that solution will obey ohms law too since I am not talking about non ohmic conductors.
If you think it doesn't then give explanation for why it obeys when you use a battery and a metal wire and why it does not apply for transformers.

Comment: what about the POWER!!!  ;D

Comment: Directly saying due to conservation of energy or P is directly proportional to V and I is not a reason for why it happens so.

Comment: @user6760 What if i ask you why V=IR in case of using a 4V battery jn simple circuit? Would the reason be because of conservation of energy or power? : )

Comment: Ohm's law is a description of how resistors work. It doesn't apply to any devices except resistors. It doesn't apply to capacitors, inductors, transistors, diodes, SCRs, vacuum tubes, ..., or transformers.

Comment: @The_Photon what! What are you saying? It doesn't apply to capacitors or transformers or inductors? I know that in case of inductors, the magnetism affects it so the voltage across wire is not exactly the one applied by battery or any source. The same applies to capacitors as there is change in current du to changing voltage. But still for voltage across wire(V), V=IR. V is not the same as what Voltage is applied instead  what Voltage is throughout resistor.

Comment: @The_Photon if it doesn't apply here then tell why it doesn't apply here an.d why it applies to somewhere wherever it applies

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean to compare currents for different choices of possible coils corresponding to different output voltages, only one being actually used ?

Comment: Dear @Alfred my question is about how to calculate current amd potential difference across sceondary coil but without using the fact "power is constant".

Comment: @ArsenalCreation I still do not understand your question. What does "when voltage is increased" mean ? When you change secondaries ? Transforming primary 220V using a secondary meant to provide 12V  rather than a secondary meant to provide 6V ? Is this your question ? But what are you closing the circuit of the secondary with ?  The same large resistor ? A short-circuit ? I fail to fully visualize the situations "low voltage, high current" and "high voltage, low current". Please elaborate.

Comment: @ArsenalCreation Or do you mean, the current in the secondary compared to the current in the **primary**,  when the secondary is meant to increase the voltage, say from input 110V to output 220V ? And again, what are you closing the circuit of the secondary with ?

Comment: Yes i mean the voltage across secondary as compared to primary. And do the same with current.

Comment: The total current through the transformer doesn’t change. It simply is divided among different number of coil wounds. The magnetic field doesn’t care how many turns the wire does. The total current sum in all the wounds is the same in the primary and secondary coils.

Comment: @ArsenalCreation I have edited your question according to your last reply to my comments, and have answered it carefully, and I hope in a convincing way... You are right about energy, or rather power. It **is** conserved, but its conservation is not enough to find the solution.

Comment: @safesphere What if I increase the number of coils in secondary coil without changing thickness of wire? Would there be any change in current? Why

Comment: By increasing the total cross section of the wire you would increase the number of electrons in the field, but it is harder for the field to move more electrons, so the current wouldn’t change. Energy conservation still applies (within the limits where you can ignore technological losses).

Answer (score 2):

If the output from the secondary of a transformer is connected to a fixed load (such as a resistor), an increased voltage will produce an increased current. This will require an increase in the current in the primary (in phase with the input voltage to match the output power).

Answer (score 1):

P = VI

I = P/V

So if we keep the load constant then it means that power to be delivered to the load from secondary is also constant.

So in this case the load which is constant will draw more current if the secondary voltage is decreased. And load will draw less current if the voltage is increased. It's the load which  determines the amount of current flow through it.

Comment: Power is not delivered! Electric fields and magnetic fields are delivered. Power comes later. Don't be too fast. Explain for electromagnetism in this

Answer (score 1):

It’s the other way around: increasing current cancels some of the B field in the coils, which reduces the induced voltage.

The voltage induced in the coil is due to the (time rate of change of) the total magnetic field.  Both the current in the primary and secondary currents contribute to that field.  By Lenz's law, the secondary current *reduces* the magnetic field.  The more secondary current -> the less total magnetic field -> the less change in the magnetic field -> the less voltage induced on the secondary.

In the limit of no current in the secondary, you get the maximum voltage.

In the limit of no resistance in the secondary (shorted), you get the maximum possible current, which is just enough to cancel the complete magnetic field, which in turn results in no voltage across the output:  That's what's needed if the output is shorted.

You can make this all mathematical if desired, but the qualitative form is important to understand.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail if it is correct?

Comment: Updated the answer to have more detail.

Comment: If i assume that changes(current and voltage) taking place inside secondary coil are quick or almost instantaneous then, would not the current change in secondary coil with respect to voltage across it. So even if you produce a current in secondary coil that reduces the initial voltage across it, the current will also change.

Comment: Transformers are generally used in AC (sine and cosine) circuits. You can also analyze for more complex waveforms, but it’s more complex. Note that if you “produce” a current, that’s the current. Period. Then only the voltage can vary in response.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question it is necessary to explain how a transformer works. Also you have to understand the complex notation for currents and voltage. I am not going to explain it, if you don't understand it, please check some physics textbooks.

Both coils of the transformer are wound around the same core. Let us say that the primary goes around the core $N_1$ times and the secondary $N_2$ times.

Depending on the size of the core and the exact nature of the ferromagnetic substance in it the magnetic flux in the core caused by a current $I$ in a single loop will be $\Phi =\ell I$. Consider a current $I_1$ in the primary and a current $I_2$ in the secondary. For convenience I am counting the relative directions of the currents in opposite ways so the total flux in the core is

$$\Phi_{core}=\ell (N_1 I_1-N_2 I_2)$$

The total flux in the primary is $\Phi_1 = N_1\Phi_{core}$ because it wounds $N_1$ times, while the in the secondary it is $\Phi_2 =N_2 \Phi_{core}$

The calculations would be much more complicated if one takes into account Ohmic losses in the coils. Therefore I will suppose that the coils are perfect conductors, and ignore Ohmic losses in them. This of course is not exactly true, but it better be a good approximation, otherwise your transformer will cost you a lot of money in charges from the Electricity Company...

In the absence of Ohmic losses inside the transformer, the voltage difference between the endpoints of the primary and secondary are $-d\Phi_1/ dt$ and $-d\Phi_2/ dt$ respectively. In complex notation the time derivative, for an alternating current of frequency $\nu$ (for instance 50 periods per second)  is obtained by multiplying by the complex number $-i\omega$ where $\omega=2\pi \nu$. To simplify notation I will call $L$ the quantity $2\pi \nu \ell$ but remember, here $L$ already takes into account $\omega$ and thus my notations differ from the usual ones.

With all these preliminaries the voltage at the primary is $iLN_1(N_1 I_1-N_2 I_2)$. I also assume your Electricity Company has enough power to guarantee that this voltage is indeed the promised one, namely $V$, be it 110V or 220V, whatever amount of electricity you use (assuming there are no losses in the wiring inside your apartment, which is not exactly true but better be *also* a good approximation.....)

So at the primary we have
$$V=iLN_1(N_1 I_1-N_2 I_2)$$
and therefore at the secondary the voltage is
$$iLN_2(N_1 I_1-N_2 I_2)=(N_2/N_1) V$$
If $N_2$ is larger than $N_1$ you have a voltage raising transformer.

Now what are you doing to do with this output voltage ? If you run an electric motor, things will be too complicated. Just assume you run
it through a pure Ohmic resistor, for instance a light bulb of resistance $R$.

Then the current $I_2$ in the secondary circuit will be
$$I_2=(N_2/N_1) V/R$$

Now we can calculate $I_1$. We have
$$iLN_2(N_1 I_1-N_2 I_2)=R I_2$$
Thus
$$iLN_2N_1 I_1=(iLN_2^2+R )I_2 \to I_1=(N_2/N_1-iR/(LN_1N_2)\ )I_2$$

The ratio $I_1/I_2$ is the complex number $N_2/N_1-iR/(LN_1N_2)$ !
In normal utilisation context, $R$ is small compared to $LN_2^2$ (remember that in my notations $\omega$ is already counted into the definition of $L$ which is **not** the usual notation). So the imaginary part is small, and the ratio $I_1/I_2$ is **close to** the real number $N_2/N_1$.

In the case of a voltage raising transformer, the current in the primary is larger than in the secondary by a complex number **close to** the real number $N_2/N_1$, which can be expressed as

In the case of a voltage raising transformer, the current in the secondary is smaller than in the primary by a complex number **close to** the real number $N_1/N_2$, in normal utilisation.

But what happens if $R$ is large ? Than the imaginary part of the ratio $I_1/I_2$ becomes larger than the real part ! But it does not mean that $I_1$ becomes larger, it means $I_2$ becomes smaller. In fact
$$I_1=(\ (N_2/N_1)^2/R-i/(LN_1^2)\ )V$$
If there is nothing plugged into the secondary, it amounts to an infinite $R$. $I_2$ is zero, of course, but **not** $I_1$ (unless you also unplug the primary). But then this current is purely imaginary.

What ! When nothing is plugged in the secondary, there still is a current in the secondary ? And the company is charging me for it ?

No. An imaginary current does not produce power. You are only charged for power, not current. The meter of the Electrical Company only measures the real part of the current, the power producing one, not the imaginary one. It is built that way on purpose.

It you consider the power, indeed in the resistor, you have voltage $(N_2/N_1)V$ and current $I_2$. The **real** part of $I_1$, the only power producing one is $(N_2/N_1)I_2$ and delivered at potential $V$. So the power is indeed the same.

But you are right. Just the argument of power would not allow you to compute the imaginary part of $I_1$, which is present even with nothing plugged into the secondary.

But nothing is perfect, and there are Ohmic losses everywhere, the current $I_1$ is never **purely** imaginary when the secondary is unplugged, and thus the Electricity Company will measure its real part and charge it to you. So to save money and help our planet, do unplug the primary when you do not use the secondary.

Comment: Thus
$iLN2N1I1=(iLN22+R)I2→I1=(N2/N1−iR/(LN1N2) )I2$
                      On the most right hand side, i should be below $R$. Check it

Comment: @ArsenalCreation $i^2=-1$ So indeed $+R/i$ is the same thing as $-iR$. The usual convention, which I have followed, is to avoid $i$ at the denominator, always bring it to the numerator by changing  the global sign.

Comment: "If there is nothing plugged into the secondary, it amounts to an infinite R" So you are saying that vaccum has infinite resistance. It is not true.  How do you came up with term "inaginary current "?

Comment: What do you mean, it is not true ? For all practical purposes, if you don't plug anything, there is no current flowing. There might be some leaks, the plastic insulators are never **perfectly** insulating so you do have a non-infinite resistance, but that goes through matter, not vacuum. Current through air would cause a visible spark.

Comment: @ArsenalCreation "Imaginary" current means in quadrature of phase with voltage. "real" current means in phase with voltage. It can all be done with sines and cosines, but it is a pain in the neck. Complex notation for currents when self-inductance and also capacitors enter the problem are standard notation.

Comment: Have you seen the charge moving in vaccum out of tesla coil?   https://youtu.be/WM25pUsrODk

Comment: @ArsenalCreation As you say, when it **does** go through, you see it. But do you see it between the exit of the secondary when nothing is plugged ?  I did speak of the possiblilty of  **visible** spark. But I'm supposing there is no such **visible** spark. And it is through very dilute gas, not really vacuum. And anyway leakage through insiulators would really  make $R$ finite. But **HUGE**. Again, for all practical purposes, infinite or zillions of times larger than the other term, what is the difference ?

Comment: But still you can have a current through vaccum if you can provide sufficient electric field or force on electrons so that they can leave the conductor or whatever material in which they are held. There is no problem for electrons moving through vaccum but it is hard for them to leave that bunch of atoms. On the other hand it can go way more complex to understand electron flow through vaccum because if you are using batteries both terminals require charge to be gained or loose at the same time Therefore no current should flow in case of batteries.

Comment: @ArsenalCreation This thing about current in vacuum is totally outside the question. Current leaks through the insulator do make the resistance **FINITE BUT HUGE** so there you avoid infinite resistance.