# Many things that plug into the wall for power, use a transformer inside, so are not physically connected to the mains, do they consume mains energy?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction

**Question**
Many things( hairdryers etc etc ) that plug into the wall / mains for power, use a transformer inside, so are not physically connected to the mains, do they consume mains energy ?

- I assume that more resistance ( load ) on the secondary windings of the transformer causes more resistance on the primary windings / wall-mains wiring, and thats power consumption.
- For example - If an incandescent-light-bulb puts more resistance on the secondary windings of the transformer which causes more resistance on the primary windings / wall-mains wiring, thats power consumption

Surely this question has been asked before on this site, any links ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any hair dryers that use transformers. Can you cite any examples?

Comment: there is no such thing as a free lunch

Comment: hotel hair dryers, look to me like they just use a transformer, for safety

Comment: Surely this exact question has been asked before on this site, any links ?

Comment: Well, if you are sure this question has been asked before on this site, you should look for links on this answers... This is the purpose of this site anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Used to be such devices were called "vampires." Two pointy teeth sucking up a little bit of power. Although some of them have a ground pin as well as the two ordinary pins.

Most devices with transformers have more than just transformers. They usually have rectifiers and batteries and a circuit to charge up the batttery. Some examples are the charger for your phone or other such hand-held device, the power supply for your lap top computer, the backup power for your LED alarm clock, etc. They have an isolation transformer to reduce the possibility of ground fault. Then there is a rectifier of some kind. Then a cirucuit to check out your batttery level and decide if it needs charging. Possibly one or more LEDs to indicate their current operating mode, whether they are connected to the AC power, if the battery is charging or charged, maybe some other things.

Such devices usually consume a very small amount of power when the main device is not in use. If you leave your phone charger plugged in it will be using a small amount of power all of the time. Same for your lap top charger, etc.

There was a push during they early 2000's to try to get people to switch to devices that used less standby power. The idea is that, even if they only use a few watts each, there are 10's of millions of them. Anybody with two or three hand-held devices will have similar numbers of them. Maybe more since they  might have one for the office and one for home. You might find it annoying to have to carry your charger around, and they are usually not too expensive. So it might be the case that having people unplug these things when not in use would save many MW of power in a large city.  It would be possible for the device to know when something was plugged in for charging and only use power when it was. However, [the media chose to mock](https://www.ogj.com/general-interest/government/article/17260635/bush-signs-energy-vampire-order) the president at the time for calling them "vampires." So this particular thing went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/685352/244116) I gave to a different question, but which explains how the transformer consumes energy from the mains.

Comment: so putting more of a load ( resistance ) on the secondary means more strain on the primary

Comment: @infomtn  Well, rather the contrary ! Putting more load, therefore more strain, is obtained by putting a **smaller** resistance that allows a larger current to flow ! The voltage of the mains is constant, and also the voltage between the plugs of the secondary coil. The smaller the resistance, the larger the current in the secondary, thus the larger the "useful" (real rather than imaginary) current in the  primary circuit.

Comment: What I meant was, and removing the word strain - More resistance ( load ) on the secondary windings of the transformer causes more resistance on the primary windings / wall-mains wiring, and thats power consumption. - If an incandescent-light-bulb puts more resistance on the secondary windings of the transformer which causes more resistance on the primary windings / wall-mains wiring, thats power consumption

Comment: Well, did you read my answer at he link gave you ? More load is obtained with less resistance. A powerful bulb, that gives a lot of light, has **less** resistance than a weak bulb that gives little light. If you do not plug **anything at all*, the resistance is not zero, it is infinite !

Comment: Apart from the fact that you understand the word "resistance" the wrong way, if you use "conductance" (inverse of resistance) instead, you  are right. More **conductance** on the secondary causes, *in some sense* (see my post there), more **conductance** on the primary, thus increasing consumption, yes.

Comment: thanks - so if a household plugged something ( that has the same thickness of wiring as the leads to the socket ) into a socket to simply let the current flow back into the socket, without any heat radiated ( little )  or kinetic energy produced, then it looks like that it would actually ( in a way 'ironically ) be consuming maximum possible energy consumption. That actually makes sense, since that would result in less energy available to flow in the rest of the grid - although that should obviously blow a fuse

Comment: @infomtn   It would indeed blow a fuse. But contrary to what you say, without kinetic energy produced there would be a **huge** amount of heat produced, that, instead of being radiated, could quite possible start a fire in the household. Indeed the heat would be produced all along the electric wiring in the house. The voltage from the company, at the entrance of the house electrical circuit would be the same but the primary would essentially become a short-circuit itself, so the only resistance would be that of the wiring. Recipe for disaster.